# Finding the longest collision (chain) in hashtable

Tags: c++, hashtable, collision

I need to find and output the longest collision that occurs when inserting into the hash table. I know I have to record all the collision counts and find which one is the largest but I'm stuck on figuring out how.

Here is my code:

```
class Entry {
private:
    int key;
    string value;
    Entry *next;
public:
    Entry(int key, string value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    int getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    void setValue(string value) {
        this->value = value;
    }
    Entry *getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    void setNext(Entry *next) {
        this->next = next;
    }
};

const int TABLE_SIZE = 587;

class HashMap {
private:
    Entry **table;
public:
    HashMap() {
        table = new Entry*[TABLE_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        table[i] = NULL;
        }

void insert(int key, string value) {
    int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
    if (table[hash] == NULL)
        table[hash] = new Entry(key, value);
    else {
        Entry *entry = table[hash];
        while (entry->getNext() != NULL)
            entry = entry->getNext();
        if (entry->getKey() == key)
            entry->setValue(value);
        else
            entry->setNext(new Entry(key, value));      
    }
}

int sizeofTable()
{
    return TABLE_SIZE;
}

~HashMap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
        if (table[i] != NULL) {
            Entry *prevEntry = NULL;
            Entry *entry = table[i];
            while (entry != NULL) {
                prevEntry = entry;
                entry = entry->getNext();
                delete prevEntry;
            }
        }
    delete[] table;
}

};
```

Is there a simple way to do this in "insert"? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to output the collision count (AKA how many entries at that index) for each insert? Or do you want some function to output the longest chain in the hashtable?

Comment: I don't want to output the collision count at an index, I want to output the longest chain, so a function to output that would be what I need to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create integer variables `maxChain` and `maxChainIndex` which keep track of the longest chain and its index, respectively.
And your insert function would be something like:

```
void insert(int key, string value) {
    int hash = (key % TABLE_SIZE);
    int chain = 1;
    if (table[hash] == NULL)
        table[hash] = new Entry(key, value);
    else {
        Entry *entry = table[hash];
        while (entry->getNext() != NULL) {
            ++chain; //Count the entries as we're searching for the last one
            entry = entry->getNext();
            }
        if (entry->getKey() == key)
            entry->setValue(value);
        else {
            entry->setNext(new Entry(key, value)); 
            ++chain; //+1 for the newly inserted element.
           }   
    }
    if(chain > maxChain) { 
        maxChain = chain;
        maxChainIndex = hash;
        cout << "Current longest collision: " << maxChain << " at index: "
             << maxChainIndex << endl;
    }  
}
```

And you can make a function to retrieve the `maxChain` like:

```
int getLongestChain() {
    return maxChain;
}
```